# Replace/repaint all pixels with one color in image with interpolated from neighboring pixels

Tags: imagemagick

I have a GIF image generated by a program where each output value is represented by its color via attached color palette. I need to replace one value, i.e. color from image with interpolated from neighboring pixels. Since I don't have possibility to alter programs output, I need to modify the output image. The resulting image will be saved in the PNG or GIF format.

I can easily extract (mask) all pixels that need repainting, since they have fixed color, but I was unable to find solution on how to replace a color of one/all pixels in imagemagick with interpolated color from neighboring pixels.
Is there a way to do this in imagemagick?

The raw values of the pixels are proportional to the physical value, so it would be great if the interpolation could be done on raw values that are then later transformed to the color via supplied color palette.

Attached image shows the original (left) and processed manually in GIMP (right).

[image: Original and processed image]

Comment: You likely need an inpainting tool. ImageMagick does not have such. You can find that with OpenCV or with Skimage. If you provide your original image a its original resolution, I can try to fill that with some morphology in ImageMagick, but it will not be exactly what you require in terms of averaging neighboring pixels excluding the ones in question.

Comment: You can do this using a median blur filter. This replace a pixel color by the most frequent value in the pixels around it. There is one in Gimp 2.10. By definition it won't create new colors, so the colors of the result will be in the color palette already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One technique is to replace the offending color with the background, and then use a combination of erode & dilate morphology to remove the paths.

Given...

[image: input.png]

```
convert input.png \
        -fill white -fuzz 10% -opaque black \
        -morphology Erode Diamond \
        -morphology Dilate Diamond \
        output.png
```

[image: output.png]

It's not a true interpolate from nearest neighbors, but close. Also note the rounding errors across edges.

[image: edge rounding errors]

---

**Updated**

Or as Fred pointed out in the comments, just use `-morphology Smooth Diamond` instead of Erode + Dilate

```
convert input.png \
        -fill white -fuzz 10% -opaque black \
        -morphology Smooth Diamond \
        output.png
```

Comment: The erode dilate combination is the same as doing `-morphology smooth diamond`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using following set of commands (fmw42 gave me an idea to use composite images):
`convert input.gif -fill white -opaque black  -morphology Smooth Diamond tmp_smooth.gif`; `convert input.gif -transparent black tmp_transparent.gif`; `convert tmp_smooth.gif null: tmp_transparent.gif -layers Composite out.gif`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a bit to xenoid's suggestion, you want to create a mask image and use that to composite the median filter with the original, so that only the region about the line is changed. Using emcconville's image and ImageMagick:

[image]

```
convert img.png \
\( -clone 0 -statistic median 3x3 \) \
\( -clone 0 -fuzz 10% -fill white +opaque black -fill black +opaque white -negate \) \
-compose over -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

An alternate, but slightly longer approach, is to put the mask into the alpha channel of the filtered image and then composite it over the original, which produces exactly the same result:

```
convert img.png \
\( -clone 0 -statistic median 3x3 \) \
\( -clone 0 -fuzz 10% -fill white +opaque black -fill black +opaque white -negate \) \
\( -clone 1 -clone 2 -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \) \
-delete 1,2 \
-compose over -composite \
result.png
```

Unfortunately, there is a slight dark residual to the upper left between the red and green. I tried increasing both the fuzz value and the filter size, but that did not seem to help. I am not sure why.